Sufficient condition for interpolation
If we have a couple of two compatible banach spaces (in this sense) $(X,Y)$ and  a sequence of Banach spaces $\{Z\}_{\theta\in[0,1]}$ which are intermediate between $X$ and $Y$  satisfying:

$Z_0=X$, $Z_1=Y$
$\|f\|_{Z_\theta}\leq\|f\|_{X}^{1-\theta}\|f\|_{{Y}}^{\theta}$ for every $\theta\in[0,1]$.

Can we deduce under these conditions that $(X,Y)_{\theta}=Z_{\theta}$? Where $(X,Y)_{\theta}$ is  the complex interpolation space between $X$ and $Y$.

I don't think such condition exist other than return to the holomorphic functions essentially. Whenever condition 2 is satisfied we call $(X,Y)\to Z_\theta$ an interpolation function with exact type $\theta$. Real interpolations can also be such example if you choose parameters carefully.
